# automatic out-of-bounds checking on global device memory in CUDA 5?

Tags: cuda, indexoutofboundsexception

I recently installed CUDA 5 (and am using Visual Studio 2010 Express, if that matters).  When I try to perform an out-of-bounds read-access on a global memory device array in a kernel, CUDA now gives me an error (Error 30 'unknown error').  I am wondering if this seemingly automatic out-of-bounds error checking is a new addition to CUDA 5.  I do not recall seeing it in earlier versions.

Additionally, is there anyway to turn off this automatic out-of-bounds error checking?  Having this capability turned on forces me to add additional conditional logic to my kernels (whereas before I just wouldn't use the out-of-bounds results).

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: I think that at this moment, half of SO is queuing up to tell you that you really need to fix your kernel, so I thought I might as well be the first: You really need to fix your kernel :)

Comment: It's not ok to write out of bounds even if you don't plan on using those values. You never know what you will be overwriting. You could be overwriting the code of your kernel, temporary storage used by the compiler (spilled registers), all kinds of stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am getting this error when I try to READ out-of-bounds.  I am not trying to write out-of-bounds.

Comment: One "fix" might be to allocate some extra space at the end of your buffers.

Comment: Kind of reminds me of [runaway truck ramps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_truck_ramp) :)

Comment: This is a device exception, not a software exception. There is no way to disable this hardware exception. I do not think compute capability < 2.0 (tesla) reported out of bounds memory exceptions. Compute capability ?= 2.0 (Fermi and Kepler) both report this exception and kill the kernel. You can use cuda-memcheck, cuda-gdb, or Nsight VSE Debugger/Memcheck to identify the incorrect code.

Comment: If you don't want code for guarding against out-of-bounds accesses, you may want to look into accessing the data via textures. With textures, you could specify one of four modes that controls the behavior in case of an out-of-bounds access: wrap, clamp, border, mirror. In some cases the choice is limited to clamp.

Comment: Lots of good ideas here!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a device exception, it is not coming from the software. The only reason it didn't crash on you before is pure luck (and, likely, older compiler). You cannot rely on compiler behaviour (e.g. even with the old compiler you might've seen different behaviour for different optimization levels)

Answer (score 0):

Considering my experiences out-of-bounds error checking is also in older CUDA versions but it doesn't behave very strictly. Launching kernels with more threads and larger allocated arrays caused kernel crashing more often than launching of smaller kernels with smaller arrays when some thread exceeded bounds of allocated array.

I suppose this checking is done by CUDA runtime system and there is no way how to turn it off. Agreeing with @Roger Dahl it definitely wouldn't be "OK" to write out of bounds if there were such way of turning this checking off.

Comment: Sorry, I had not noticed your (@Aaron) comment before posting this answer. But reading the documentation to NVCC, there is no such way to turn this checking off.